# reading data from trupulse 360 C#

Tags: c#, bluetooth

**Trupulse 360B** - a device that can measure the distance to any object.
It reads the data and sends it in this form:
**$PLTIT,HV,HDvalue,units,AZvalue,units,INCvalue, units,SDvalue,units,*csum**

I need to get this data on my PC **using BLUETOOTH**

Application should be written in c #

MANUAL - http://wiki.awf.forst.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/images/7/71/TruPulse_360-B_Users_Manual_2nd_Edition_English.pdf

Thanks!

data is not always there, from 10 times goes 2-3 times normally, in other cases blank lines appear.What am I doing wrong?

```html
private static void Connect(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            if (result.IsCompleted)
            {
                // client is connected now :)
                Console.WriteLine(BC.Connected);
                stream = BC.GetStream();

                if (stream.CanRead)
                {
                    byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[1024];
                    StringBuilder myCompleteMessage = new StringBuilder();
                    int numberOfBytesRead = 0;

                    // Incoming message may be larger than the buffer size. 
                    NmeaParser.StreamDevice truepulse = new NmeaParser.StreamDevice(stream);
                    truepulse.OpenAsync();
                    do
                    {
                        numberOfBytesRead = stream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
                        myCompleteMessage.AppendFormat(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer));
                    }
                    while (stream.DataAvailable);


                    // Print out the received message to the console.
                    Console.WriteLine("You received the following message : " + myCompleteMessage);
                }


                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Sorry.  You cannot read from this NetworkStream.");
                }

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

Comment: and what is your problem now ? have you tried anything ? **SO is not a code writing service ....**

Comment: Why do you think that all data MUST be received in single packet? Why do you think underlying Bluetooth driver knows how long data must be. When you work with any communication device you must know when data packet ends and you can process it. Until it ends you have to store received data in your internal temporary buffer. I guess the termination if CRLF so read until get CRLF.